# Unable to display systray icon's menu for a Wine application

Tags: gnome, wine, window, 23.04

In previous versions of Ubuntu we did not have this problem. Now, after the update from Ubuntu 22.10 to 23.04 (GNOME / Xorg), a Wine application that is minimized to system tray *does* have its icon displayed in systray; however, I am no longer able to interact with this icon either by right or left clicking. No menu is displayed.